# Problem with Left Join - matching Number

Tags: mysql, sql, database, report

See the SQL query below, it count the number of Yes and No between the `CheckDate`

On the `MatchSales` field - it do not work how I wanted to be. It should find `D.MobileNO`  (depending on the `CheckDate`) match to `S.mobile` (Check all record in the `sales` table)

```
SELECT D.Username, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= $From_timestamp AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= $To_timestamp THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'No' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= $From_timestamp AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= $To_timestamp THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as No, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN S.mobile IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as MatchSales
FROM dairy as D 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales) as S on D.MobileNo = S.mobile
WHERE source = 'Company' 
GROUP BY D.Username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply add the Checkdate condition from your `CASE` to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT D.Username,      
      SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes,      
      SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'No'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No,      
      SUM(CASE WHEN S.mobile IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS MatchSales 
 FROM dairy AS D     
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales) AS S ON D.MobileNo = S.mobile 
 WHERE D.source = 'Company'  
 AND   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(D.CheckDate) >= $From_timestamp 
 AND   UNIX_TIMTIMESTAMP(D.CheckDate) <= $To_timestamp 
 GROUP BY D.Username
```

without it you will full scan dairy

Comment: With the date checks now in the `WHERE` clause can't you remove them from the `SUM(CASE...` statements for the "yes" and "no" counts?

Answer (score 1):

-- I think this is how you do it:

```
SELECT SUM(Yes) AS Yes, SUM(No) AS No
FROM (
    SELECT D.Username, 
        (CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= $From_timestamp AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= $To_timestamp THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Yes], 
        (CASE WHEN D.type = 'No' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= $From_timestamp AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= $To_timestamp THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [No], 
        (CASE WHEN S.mobile IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as MatchSales
    FROM dairy as D 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales) as S on D.MobileNo = S.mobile
    WHERE source = 'Company' 
    GROUP BY D.Username
) T
```

Comment: How about without the brackets ?